# Randomizing one patient per bed using vectors

Tags: c++, vector

I am pretty new to vectors. I have a program assignment where I randomly assign patients to beds. I need to make it so that I can only have one patient per bed. My question is how do I get one patient to be sorted randomly and assigned to one bed?

It's a decent size program and the code is in multiple files so bear with me. If you do not understand something let me know, I will try and clear it up the best that I can.

This is my assigning only one patient per one bed. This function is more than likely my problem.

```
string Hospital::assignRandPatientToBed()
{
    for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        for(unsigned int pi=0;pi<vBeds.size();pi++)
        {
            if(rand()%2)
            {
                 //bigRand is a function: numberToString=9      
                 vPatients[bigRand()%vPatients.size()].bedId;   ///MORE THAN  LIKELY WRONG
            }
        }
    }
    return "Random Beds assigned to Patients.\n";
}
```

The private portion of my main class, hospital.h

```
private:
    int nextPatientIDtoBeUsed;
    vector<Patient> vPatients;
    map<int,int> PatientIDIndex;
    map<string,int>PatientNameIndex;
    map<string,int>PatientCategoryIndex;

    int nextDoctorIDtoBeUsed;
    vector<Doctor> vDoctors;
    map<int,int> DoctorIDIndex;

    int nextBedIDtoBeUsed;
    vector<Bed> vBeds;
    map<int, int> BedIDIndex;
};
```

Header file for Bed.h

```
class Bed 
{
   friend class Hospital;

   public:

   private:
   int id;
   string location;
   string bedType;
   int patientID;
};
```

Header file portion of the patient.h(i only use the private portion for this purpose its a big header file).

```
private:
    int id;
    vector<int> doctorIDs;
    int bedId;
};
```

My Output that I have to fix. Bed is assigned by 500, the patient is the 8927 number.

```
     500 CDDIUTEIOJ
            892795431 Muw, Eziel (174) 094-8824
            892795431 Muw, Eziel (174) 094-8824
            892795431 Muw, Eziel (174) 094-8824
            892795431 Muw, Eziel (174) 094-8824
            892795431 Muw, Eziel (174) 094-8824
     501 CMPSAJLFVG
            892795431 Muw, Eziel (174) 094-8824
            892795431 Muw, Eziel (174) 094-8824
            892795431 Muw, Eziel (174) 094-8824
            892795431 Muw, Eziel (174) 094-8824
            892795431 Muw, Eziel (174) 094-8824
```

It is taking the first name that is randomly created and assigning it to the bed. For the output, I chose to add 5 patients to 5 beds, but I cut it off after 2 because it just repeats 5 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general principle when doing "randomly distribute items of vector V to slots in container C" is something like this:

1. Pick a random number in the range 0..C.size()-1 into R
2. Check if slot C[R] is available. If not repeat step 1.
3. Pick the next available item in V, and insert into C[R].
4. If not all V done, go back to 1.

Comment: Ok, So I am missing a function for checking if a slot is available?

Comment: Or "not used" or something like that, yes. The random shuffle suggested by collapser is another way of solving the same problem, of course. Although that assumes that you don't need to have the beds in a particular order within the vector.

Comment: OO ok yea I want to have the beds in numerical order, but random patients added to them. 

Why does .push_back() not work with beds?? We used it for doctors being assigned to patients but it doesn't work for beds.

Comment: vDoctors[DoctorIDIndex[drID]].patientIDs.push_back(patID); <-Works here    
    
vBeds[BedIDIndex[bedID]].patientID.push_back(patID); <-Doesnt work here.

In the doctor.h file you have  int id; vector<int> patientIDs;
and in patient.h you have int id; vector<int>doctorIDs; 

I notice bed.h doesnt have it a vector.

Comment: No, it's just a single `int`, so when the bed is empty it has some "not in use" value, and when it is in use, it as the id of the patient - since you don't want to have more than one patient per bed, you don't need a vector, and thus no need to use push_back, just assign the id of the patient to the bed's patientID of the bed.

Comment: Awesome, Thank You, So in terms of my random assign function, change the for loop to vPatients.size() instead of vBeds.size(). ..and change the line of code


 vPatients[pi].bedId(vBeds[bigRand()%vBeds.size()].patientID);

Although vPatients[pi] is prompting an error. I would do something like that?

Comment: You need to check that there isn't another patient in the bed already - and fix any compiler errors - without at least seeing the error, it's hard to say what the problem is.

Answer (score 2):

idea:

start off with the `vBeds` vector and use the [`random_shuffle` function template](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/random_shuffle/) from the c++ stl to iterate in a random order through beds. once you have a new patient to assign, you take the next iteration and use this bed. you will want to have list of beds returned to the pool of available beds by maintaining an explicit free bed list `fbl`.

the assertion would be that the remaining elements in your iterator concatenated with `fbl` is equivalent to the pool of all beds available. if you've reached the end of the iterator you re-create it over `fbl`, setting `fbl` to a new empty list thereafter.

Answer (score 2):

You could also apply a random permutation to the *beds* instead of the *patients*. Then you can assign patients in the order in which they arrive and they will be mapped to random beds. Since your `bed` class contains an `id` attribute, you will not lose any information by this approach.

See [the random shuffle algorithm](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/random_shuffle/) for an example of how to do this.

Comment: Thank you for this. I will read it and try and make it relate.